# React Private Route redirect

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a private route set up that starts with a Password page. After user typed in a password it takes them to Terms /terms. When they accept the terms there is a Link that takes them to Home /home.

Now let's say I sent someone a link to /page1. It arrives at / (login), then goes to terms, but then needs to link to /page1. However it will go to /home. Is there a programatic way to track which url was initially requested and put it into Link on the terms page, instead of /home?

Here is my code for Private Route

```
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import React from 'react';

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, isLoggedIn, ...rest }) => (
  <Route {...rest} render={props => (
    isLoggedIn ? (
      <div>
        <Component {...props}/>
      </div>
    ) : (
      <Redirect to={{
        pathname: '/',
        state: { from: props.location }
      }}/>
    )
  )}/>
)

export default PrivateRoute;
```

and here is the code for /terms

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

class Terms extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="wrapper">
        <div className="login_content">

          <div className="button"><Link to="/home">I Agree</Link></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Terms;
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have an index file where you put all your routes. Maybe you have your routes defined like this.

```
<PrivateRoute path="/mypath" component={MyComponent} />
```

Now in your component where you defined your PrivateRoute just add the path property.

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ path, component: Component, isLoggedIn, ...rest }) => (
   if (path === '/mypath') {
      // Do something
   }
    ...
)
```

That shoul help you.